# Swift: Using custom accessoryType for cell freezes UI and 99% CPU Usage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use a custom accessory type (UIImage) for my tableview cell which has a expand/collapse functionality. When user taps a cell the row expands or collpases if parent is tapped again.

The imageview I'm using to set the accessory type is below:

```
var expandIcon : UIImageView?
expandIcon  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16))
expandIcon!.image = UIImage(named:"expand")
```

Following code is when user taps a row which if its parent it should epxand or if its already expanded it will collapse.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellData = dataForCellAtRowIndex[indexPath.section]!.rows[indexPath.row]
    var cell:UITableViewCell!

    if isParentCell(indexPath.row) == true {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)            
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test" + String(indexPath.row)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "detail"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.accessoryView = expandIcon

    }else{
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("childCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "child name"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "child detail"
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    return cell
}
```

The bit that is causing the problem is `cell.accessoryView = expandAccessory` which causes the UI to freeze and cpu usage goes to 99% as reported by xcode. if i remove `cell.accessoryView = expandIcon` everything is fine! Why is this happening?

Comment: Typo? You have `expandAccessory` and `expandIcon`.

Comment: Do you have a single `expandAccessory` that you are trying to assign to multiple rows?  That won't work

Comment: FYI - you can't reuse the same image view over and over like this since a view can only have one parent.

Comment: sorry fixed expandAccesssory - it should be called expandIcon

Comment: thanks @rmaddy that was indeed the issue!

Comment: Have you tried clicking the pause button and using Xcode's debug navigator (or using Instruments) to see what the app is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this as @rmaddy mentioned was the reuse of UIImage view which was causing the UI freeze. Creating a new UIImage for each cell fixed my problem so instead of:

```
if isParentCell(indexPath.row) == true {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)            
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test" + String(indexPath.row)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "detail"
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.accessoryView = expandIcon

}
```

i had to :

```
if isParentCell(indexPath.row) == true {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)            
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test" + String(indexPath.row)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "detail"
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //put the below two lines in a func and return a UIImage 
    let expandIcon  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16))
    expandIcon.image = UIImage(named:"expand")

    cell.accessoryView = expandIcon

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should implement a function to return an expandIcon and then call it in place of expandIcon variable.

```
func expandImageView() -> UIImageView {
    let expandIcon  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16))
    expandIcon.image = UIImage(named:"expand")
    return expandIcon
}
```

`cell.accessoryView = expandImageView()`